# EPiServer Chrome vs IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, episerver

i know EPi is designed for IE. I have a weird problem.

Im debugging a custom made Tag function that is not working properly.

The function has a list with available tags, seleceted tags and an ADD button to bring tags from the first list to the second list.

In IE and FIREFOX the css is a bit broken and when you click the ADD button you are asked if you want to leave the page. If you "leave" it the page reloads and the tag is selected.

In Chrome it works perfectly. The CSS is not broken and when you click ADD the tag is added without anything about leaving the page.

Im running EPi CMS 6 R2

IE HTML OUTPUT for the ADD button:

```
<input name="ctl00$FullRegion$PC_52_1$EditForm$Tags$ctl01$addButton" title="Add to list" class="epi-cmsButton-text epi-cmsButton-tools epi-cmsButton-Add" id="ctl00_FullRegion_PC_52_1_EditForm_Tags_ctl01_addButton" onmouseover="EPi.ToolButton.MouseDownHandler(this)" onmouseout="EPi.ToolButton.ResetMouseDownHandler(this)" onclick="WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$FullRegion$PC_52_1$EditForm$Tags$ctl01$addButton", "", true, "", "", false, false))" type="submit" value="Add"/>
```

CHROME HTML OUTPUT for the ADD button:

```
<input class="epi-cmsButton-text epi-cmsButton-tools epi-cmsButton-Add" type="submit" name="ctl00$FullRegion$PC_52_1$EditForm$Tags$ctl01$addButton" id="ctl00_FullRegion_PC_52_1_EditForm_Tags_ctl01_addButton" value="Add" title="Add to list" onmouseover="EPi.ToolButton.MouseDownHandler(this)" onmouseout="EPi.ToolButton.ResetMouseDownHandler(this)" onclick="WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$FullRegion$PC_52_1$EditForm$Tags$ctl01$addButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))">

FIREFOX:
```

Any one with experience on how to solve this?

Comment: Which EPi version are you running?

Comment: CMS 6 R2 has official support for Firefox as well as IE. How's the output when using Firefox?

Comment: I added the FF output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it. Place it on the Episerer:ToolButton. DisablePageLeaveCheck="true".

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this warning using the ScriptDisablePageLeaveEvent control.

Follow [this](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/1/disable-page-leave-check-for-postbacks-inside-custom-property-controls-in-episerver/) helpful guide.

Answer (score 0):

Different HTML rendering can usually be avoided by putting or changing .browser-files in the App_Browsers folder.